# Pjax to run page specific scripts

Tags: jquery, ajax, pjax

I am creating an app and i am using pjax for pages navigation. My main concern is that by using pjax, scripts that are specific to some pages will not run with pjax.
The only way to make everything work is to include scripts in pjax:end (or success) as well as duplicate them in $(document).ready(function() {//scripts here}
is this the only solution and performance wise, because now i have the code duplicated in both pjax as well as $(document).ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for your questing is Yes!.
The scripts in your document.ready will only works on the loading, and it is not working in your pjax response pages. so you have to duplicate the script in both pjax response and document.ready.